# qUnit doesnt work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>qUnit basic example</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6606/trunk/jquery/test/data/testsuite.css"/>
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5920/trunk/qunit/testrunner.js"></script>
        <script>
            test("a basic test example",function(){
                ok(true,"This test is fine");
                var value="hello";
                equals(value,"hello","We expect value to be hello");
            });


             test("222222222",function(){
                ok(true,"This t fine");
                var value="hello";
                equals(value,"hllo","We eaaaaaaaavalue to be hello");
            });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my mark up above. if you copy and paste it, you will se in the main the result of the test..But they are bunched up i.e. it shows the total of the number of tests compare to  the total fake. I need to see where the assertion failed, and the number of total success compare to fails per test .. how can I achieve so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use a version of QUnit so old that you are hotlinking it from the *old* VCS (and not even the latest revision in that VCS!)
2. Call your div `qunit` not `main`
3. In general, follow the instructions on the [QUnit homepage](http://qunitjs.com/)

Such:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-git.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-git.js"></script>
<!-- etc -->
<div id="qunit"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to add that in general, updating to the latest version should be one of the **first** things one should try before asking for help. Using old versions of third-party code/libraries is asking for trouble: any bugs that exist could've already been fixed, so any issues related to those bugs waste everyone's time.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I followed the instructions on jquery cookbook book. I didnt think the instructions were that old to run 2 basic tests..thanks